# Columns is going over border of a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am making a row with the columns, but having some problems with the width. The row has 2 columns, where the left one has a transparent pink color.

The problem is that the pink background-color is going over the `<div class="flex-wrap">`. I would like that everything I do within the `class="flex-wrap"` is staying in there. So the columns should not go over the border.

As I see it is on the row where it is wrong? I can see the `margin-left: 0px;`, but then the problem is on the right side, when the viewport is getting smaller.

Does somebody have a clue how to solve this?

[I have made a working JSFiddle her](https://jsfiddle.net/hv7ecmf2/)

```css
.flex-wrap .row {
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
.flex-wrap .row>[class*='col-'] {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}
.section {
 border: 1px solid #B9B9B9;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="section">
      <div class="flex-wrap">
         <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3" style="background-color: rgba(201, 76, 76, 0.3);">
        <h3>Here is a headline</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
        <img src="https://www.q95da.com/uploads/4/5/7/0/45709989/published/6391827.jpg">
     </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: here in the example, the pink is only in the headline column

Comment: Hello. Apprtly the Bootstrap is not called here? I have linked to a working example on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hv7ecmf2/

Comment: In the fiddle, the pink stays in the left column, and goes 100% of the height. Which makes sense, because you are using `flex-direction: column;`